# Failure to read from a hardware device when running in a container

Tags: linux, docker, module, kernel, podman

I have a (3rd party) hardware device (plugged into PCI slot) and a userland application that talks to it via a kernel module.

All is working well - except when i try to run it in a `podman` container - it is not happy. When running in the container the device is mapped through command line options `--device /dev/<something>` and during application's execution under `strace` i can see the device being successfully opened.
However when trying to read from the device it shows

```
ioctl(4, _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE, 0x61, 0x1, 0x8), 0x7ffe15b23390) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

so it appears like some kind of permission issue.

Tried launching the container with various flags (`--security-opt="seccompt=unconfined"`, `--cap-add=ALL`, `--privileged` etc) but none of these helped. The application is running as superuser.

Is there something else i should try?